# Word or phrase (with a sense of disapproval) meaning "undue faith in the system"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I've always wanted a term to express people having an overly strong faith in the social system. What I mean by this is when people often seem to think that there is much more thought or study that goes into making decisions, or structuring the world.

Examples:

> 1. When people are amazed or frustrated when they visit a doctor and come
>    away without a named diagnosis or cure, or not understanding that
>    names of illnesses used by doctors are often simply descriptions of
>    symptoms.
> 2. Overt faith in cooking times, or user guides as though they are gospel
>    scripture, without common sense or thought to the reasoning behind the
>    instruction might be.
> 3. Probably what is being displayed by my assumption that a word exists for such a thing.

Forgive me if I explained this poorly!

Comment: How about "blind faith"?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding. Do you want a word to describe a person who believes too easily? Then credulous is a good word, which means like gullible or they'll believe anything they read or are told. Also Hot Licks' answer of blind faith. On the other hand if you mean a person who lives day to day and doesn't wonder how things work, why or how they exist, who live what Socrates called the "unexamined life", then I think lbf's answer is good. Though, I would bet there's an even more specific term.

Answer (score 1):

**unquestioning**  [collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/unquestioning) (adv: unquestioningly)

> To accept something without further verifying or investigating

As in:

> If you describe a person or their **beliefs as unquestioning**, you are
>   emphasizing that they accept something without any doubt or
>   disagreement.

Answer (score 1):

How about "blind faith"? –Hot Licks

> **blind faith**:
>
> unquestioning belief in something, even when it's unreasonable or
> wrong

[[English Club](https://www.englishclub.com/ref/esl/Collocations/B/blind_faith_3256.php#:%7E:text=Meaning,when%20it%27s%20unreasonable%20or%20wrong)]

> **blindly**: ...
>
> 2. without understanding or using one's judgement; unthinkingly.
>
> - *don't blindly accept dogma as justification*

[[Oxford Languages, Dictionary](https://www.google.com/search?q=blindly+meaning&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&ei=y1ylZLjjK4KRgQaZq5-4Aw&ved=0ahUKEwj49M3Zw_f_AhWCSMAKHZnVBzcQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=blindly+meaning&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzIICAAQigUQkQIyBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB46CggAEEcQ1gQQsAM6CggAEIoFELADEENKBAhBGABQpg5YmxNgnhdoAXABeACAAVCIAZgBkgEBMpgBAKABAcABAcgBCg&sclient=gws-wiz-serp)]

'Blindly' is often used disapprovingly, criticising mental laziness or a slave mentality:

> **blindly**
>
> If you say that someone does something blindly, you mean that they do
> it without having enough information, or without thinking about it.
> [disapproval]

[[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/blindly)]

- *An important result of our research is that we need no longer stare blindly at the relationship between slavery and the industrial revolution.*

[['The Low Countries': 'Slavery Was of Major Importance to the Dutch Economy'_Pepijn Brandon & Ulbe Bosma, translated by Anna Asbury](https://www.the-low-countries.com/article/slavery-was-of-major-importance-to-the-dutch-economy)]

Answer (score 0):

**Unsuspecting** (adj.)

> Not suspecting; not harbouring any suspicion. [OED]

> Trusting; not realizing there is any danger or harm [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/unsuspecting)